# Oh-my-zsh theme not rendering properly in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, oh-my-zsh

Cobalt2 theme does not render properly in the terminal in IntelliJ but works fine in the Mac terminal. How do I correct this?

[image]

Comment: You should configure IntelliJ to use the patched fonts you are using on terminal. The font on your screenshot doesn' t have the special glyphs.

Answer (score 25):

Thought I'd add for anyone Googling this "zsh themes being broken in IntelliJ" ...especially Powerlevel10k ... you can conditionally switch the theme to a compatible one for your IntelliJ console, and keep the nice one for your main terminal. In `.zshrc` :

```
if [[ $__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__ ]]; then
  ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
else
  ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
fi
```

Hope that helps someone :-)

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem and this solution solved the problem. Hopefully Intellij will fix this problem in the future

Comment: This helped me out with fixing powerline and bash. Thanks so much!

Comment: FYI, PyCharm terminal here has the ENVVAR: TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm

Answer (score 12):

I'm using IntelliJ 2022.1.1 CE + Oh-My-Zsh + Powerlevel10k, below setting made it work for me:

- Go to "IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Themes" and select "Sync with OS"
- Restart IntelliJ

[image]

Result:
[image]

Credit: this answer is inspired by the answer from @Kyle Pillay.

Comment: This doesn't work with 2022.3.3 RC version of Intellij Idea. Any idea how we can solve for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please follow this known bug for updates:

- [IDEA-165506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165506) Incorrect style for zsh theme

Comment: seems like these is happening in phpstorm 2020.2 , still not resolved :(. zsh themes are not showing properly.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the color scheme in IntelliJ to the same color scheme you're using in your OS terminal should solve this.

I'm using the Dracula Theme in iTerm2, and I installed the IDE color scheme from here [Jetbrains Dracula Theme](https://draculatheme.com/jetbrains/) and it's all displaying as expected.

Here's what my PHPStorm terminal looks like now.

[image: IntelliJ(PHPStorm) Terminal with Dracula Theme]

Comment: Did u find the way to fix the incorrect height of the background line?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I didn't, would probably take some digging to fix that. I moved onto a project shortly after this post and with it came the need to use VSCode so I didn't take the time to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Select the "**JetBrains Mono**" font in the **Console Fonts** option.

Answer (score 0):

Restart configuration in IntelliJ terminal with `p10k configure` command and use powerlevel10k recommended fonts (MesloLGS NF).

1. Download all MesloLGS NF fonts here and install: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k?tab=readme-ov-file#manual-font-installation.
2. Open IntelliJ settings and navigate **Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font** and choose MesloLGS NF font. Save and exit.
3. Open IntelliJ terminal and navigate .zshrc directory with `cd` command.
4. Start powerlevel10k configuratin here again with `p10k configure` command.

I tested on PHPStorm 2023.3.6 and it is working good now.